# Is it possible to select all files (files only) in a location using the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I'm attempting to use the Graph API to select all folders and files for a SharePoint location.

I can use the following call to get a list of all `driveItems` (folders and files) in a location:

```
/drives/{drive-id}/root/children
```

I can extend this call to make it so it returns only items with the "folder" facet, meaning I can select all `driveItems` that are folders in this location:

```
drives/{drive-id}/root/children?$filter=folder ne null
```

What I want now is to be able to extend the original call so that it selects all `driveItems` with the "file" facet only. e.g. something like:

```
/drives/{drive-id}/root/children?$filter=file ne null
```

However, my experience with the Graph explorer suggests that nothing is supported that will allow me to do this.

Can anyone tell me any possible method for doing this? Hopefully using some OData parameters on `/drives` rather than using `sites/(siteId)/lists(listId)/items` - if this method were to be used, how then could i filter out Document Sets from the results?